# willSendRequestForAuthenticationChallenge is not called using iOS 7 SDK

Tags: ios, ios7, nsurlconnection

I can't get willSendRequestForAuthenticationChallenge called. 
This worked using iOS 6.1 SDK.

Maybe something changed ?